# <JSP> What is purpose of using " ${fn:....} "?

Tags: jsp

I have a code as following

```
<c:forEach begin="2013" end="${fn:substring(maps.curDate,0,4)}" step="1" var="yearList">
```

I know they use substr in SQL.

1) What does " ${fn:substring(maps.curDate,0,4)} " mean in this code?

2) What do they use  "${fn: ... " and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fn` is the conventional prefix for the JSTL Function Tag Library, which provides a set of functions that can be used with the JSP Expression Language.

The prefix is defined this way:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

In the case of `${fn:substring(maps.curDate,0,4)}`, this calls the Function Tag Library `substring` function, which takes the string parameter and returns a piece of it as defined by the indices provided. In the example, it returns the first four characters of `maps.curDate` as shown [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=JNE8sqfQNAUC&pg=PT635&lpg=PT635&dq=jsp%20fn%20substring%20exclusive&source=bl&ots=GvzQQyrqSa&sig=kzjaWYeCYzDg6NTp4Ij24Yits_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BYFfUq3ZLsa22gW3h4AI&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=jsp%20fn%20substring%20exclusive&f=false).